# an error loading batch data in druid with Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.1 (map-reduce)

Tags: cloudera-cdh, druid

I constructed the druid,and get error when loading batch data in it, as follows:

```
        2016-10-19T07:06:08,656 INFO [task-runner-0-priority-0] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - Counters: 12
        Job Counters 
            Failed map tasks=4
            Launched map tasks=4
            Other local map tasks=3
            Data-local map tasks=1
            Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=13910
            Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
            Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=13910
            Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=13910
            Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=14243840
        Map-Reduce Framework
            CPU time spent (ms)=0
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
    2016-10-19T07:06:08,657 ERROR [task-runner-0-priority-0] io.druid.indexer.DetermineHashedPartitionsJob - Job failed: job_1476065812127_0012
    2016-10-19T07:06:08,657 INFO [task-runner-0-priority-0] io.druid.indexer.JobHelper - Deleting path[var/druid/hadoop-tmp/wikiticker/2016-10-19T070532.438Z/9d778c51830e449f831a3966a679df11]
    2016-10-19T07:06:08,682 ERROR [task-runner-0-priority-0] io.druid.indexing.overlord.ThreadPoolTaskRunner - Exception while running task[HadoopIndexTask{id=index_hadoop_wikiticker_2016-10-19T07:05:32.450Z, type=index_hadoop, dataSource=wikiticker}]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-16.0.1.jar:?]
        at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopTask.invokeForeignLoader(HadoopTask.java:204) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopIndexTask.run(HadoopIndexTask.java:175) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.indexing.overlord.ThreadPoolTaskRunner$ThreadPoolTaskRunnerCallable.call(ThreadPoolTaskRunner.java:436) [druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.indexing.overlord.ThreadPoolTaskRunner$ThreadPoolTaskRunnerCallable.call(ThreadPoolTaskRunner.java:408) [druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_79]
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopTask.invokeForeignLoader(HadoopTask.java:201) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: com.metamx.common.ISE: Job[class io.druid.indexer.DetermineHashedPartitionsJob] failed!
        at io.druid.indexer.JobHelper.runJobs(JobHelper.java:343) ~[druid-indexing-hadoop-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.indexer.HadoopDruidDetermineConfigurationJob.run(HadoopDruidDetermineConfigurationJob.java:91) ~[druid-indexing-hadoop-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopIndexTask$HadoopDetermineConfigInnerProcessing.runTask(HadoopIndexTask.java:291) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at io.druid.indexing.common.task.HadoopTask.invokeForeignLoader(HadoopTask.java:201) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.9.1.1.jar:0.9.1.1]
        ... 7 more
    2016-10-19T07:06:08,687 INFO [task-runner-0-priority-0] io.druid.indexing.overlord.TaskRunnerUtils - Task [index_hadoop_wikiticker_2016-10-19T07:05:32.450Z] status changed to [FAILED].
    2016-10-19T07:06:08,688 INFO [task-runner-0-priority-0] io.druid.indexing.worker.executor.ExecutorLifecycle - Task completed with status: {
      "id" : "index_hadoop_wikiticker_2016-10-19T07:05:32.450Z",
      "status" : "FAILED",
      "duration" : 33220
    }
```

Then according to the [official solution](http://druid.io/docs/latest/operations/other-hadoop.html), I did some operations, but also of little use:

- edit Druid's pom.xml dependencies to match the version of Jackson in my Hadoop version and recompile Druid

  ```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.annotations()Ljava/lang/Iterable;
  ```
- use maven-shade-plugin to make a fat jar druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar

  ```
  java -Xmx256m -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath ~/druid-0.9.1.1/tmp/druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:~/druid-0.9.1.1/conf/druid/_common/:~/jackson-* -Ddruid.extensions.loadList=[] io.druid.cli.Main index hadoop --coordinate "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1" ../quickstart/wikiticker-index.json
  ```

excute this commond,I got:

```
    INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.druid.cli.CliInternalHadoopIndexer$1.configure(CliInternalHadoopIndexer.java:95)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:230)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.util.Modules$RealOverriddenModuleBuilder$1.configure(Modules.java:173)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:230)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.util.Modules$RealOverriddenModuleBuilder$1.configure(Modules.java:153)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:230)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at io.druid.initialization.Initialization.makeInjectorWithModules(Initialization.java:367)
        at io.druid.cli.GuiceRunnable.makeInjector(GuiceRunnable.java:60)
        at io.druid.cli.CliInternalHadoopIndexer.run(CliInternalHadoopIndexer.java:108)
        at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at io.druid.cli.CliHadoopIndexer.run(CliHadoopIndexer.java:115)
        at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:105)

    2016-10-20T05:05:52,401 ERROR [main] io.druid.cli.CliHadoopIndexer - failure!!!!
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
        at io.druid.cli.CliHadoopIndexer.run(CliHadoopIndexer.java:115) [druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:105) [druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
    Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

    1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: null
      at com.google.inject.util.Modules$RealOverriddenModuleBuilder$1.configure(Modules.java:173)

    2) Binding to null instances is not allowed. Use toProvider(Providers.of(null)) if this is your intended behaviour.
      at io.druid.cli.CliInternalHadoopIndexer$1.configure(CliInternalHadoopIndexer.java:93)

    3) Could not find a suitable constructor in io.druid.metadata.MetadataStorageTablesConfig. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
      at io.druid.metadata.MetadataStorageTablesConfig.class(MetadataStorageTablesConfig.java:35)
      at io.druid.cli.CliInternalHadoopIndexer$1.configure(CliInternalHadoopIndexer.java:95)

    3 errors
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:448) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.initialization.Initialization.makeInjectorWithModules(Initialization.java:367) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.cli.GuiceRunnable.makeInjector(GuiceRunnable.java:60) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.cli.CliInternalHadoopIndexer.run(CliInternalHadoopIndexer.java:108) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:105) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.druid.cli.CliInternalHadoopIndexer$1.configure(CliInternalHadoopIndexer.java:95) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:230) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:94) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.util.Modules$RealOverriddenModuleBuilder$1.configure(Modules.java:173) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:230) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:94) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.util.Modules$RealOverriddenModuleBuilder$1.configure(Modules.java:153) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:230) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.initialization.Initialization.makeInjectorWithModules(Initialization.java:367) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.cli.GuiceRunnable.makeInjector(GuiceRunnable.java:60) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.cli.CliInternalHadoopIndexer.run(CliInternalHadoopIndexer.java:108) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:105) ~[druid-services-0.9.1.1-selfcontained.jar:0.9.1.1]
        ... 6 more
```

Does anyone have the same problem. Anyone can help?

Comment: I've just read the official solution document.  I need to load data from HDFS on CDH, too.  I will try as well.

Comment: hi, @KenjiNoguchi Have you encountered this problem?

Comment: I've seen the "overrides final method" described in the error that is described in the official solution.  Preferably I would like to avoid compiling shaded jar.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run the indexing job.  No shaded jars necessary.  Here are the steps.

1) Download Hadoop client that matches for your CDH.  In the druid distribution directory run this command.  It will download the Hadoop-client into `hadoop-dependencies` directory.

```
 ./bin/pull-deps -r https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/ -h org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.1
```

2) Set client version in the middleManger config.

```
hadoopDependencyCoordinates=["org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.1"]
```

3) I used indexing service to run Hadoop job.  Create the JSON, and put `jobProperties` like this.

```
"jobProperties": {
  "mapreduce.job.classloader": "true",
  "mapreduce.job.classloader.system.classes": "-javax.validation.,java.,javax.,org.apache.commons.logging.,org.apache.log4j.,org.apache.hadoop.,org.xerial.snappy."
}
```

Add classes to the list as necessary if you still see some errors and know it exists in CDH and Druid.

4) HTTP POST the JSON to Overlord